# Spaces in the folder name

Tags: batch-file

as you would to get a variable in a file that is inside a folder that contains spaces in the name?

**My Code:**

```
For /f "delims=" %%x in (Files\My Folder\TEST.ini) do (set "%%x")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, if the file contents are in the adecuated format (`var=value`)

```
For /f "usebackq delims=" %%x in ("Files\My Folder\TEST.ini") do (set "%%x")
```

Quote the file name and indicate to the `for /f` command, using `usebackq` that the quoted string is not an inmediate string but an file name (see `for /?`)